# ChildAction in ASP.NET MVC 3 with Ninject and EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ninject

I am having a weird issue with an ASP.NET MVC 3 application using Ninject and EntityFramework.

We have a ISession interface, which is extended by EntitySession who is in fact a light wrapper over EntityFramework DbContext.

Here are my Ninject bindings:

```
Kernel.Bind<MyEfDbContext>().To<MyEfDbContext>().InRequestScope();
Kernel.Bind<ISession>().To<EntitySession>().InRequestScope();
```

As you can see, everything is in Request scope.

The problem is that when I execute a ChildAction, it works fine when I first hit the page, but when I refresh the page, I always get this exception, and I have to either rebuild or reset IIS to get rid of it.

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I inject the ISession in my controller, which should be disposed at the end of the request.

Executing a child action, in my mind, should not do another request, so it should use the same intance of the dbcontext as its master action.

I don't know if someone else had a similar issue with this stack.

My razor code looks like:

```
@Html.Action(MVC.Controller.Action(Model.Id))
```

Comment: Which version of ninject do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might be produced due to one of the objects referencing the MyEfDbContext has a longer life cycle that MyEfDbContext itself. Please check the dependency chain and try to identify if you are using your context from an object in the application, session, singleton scope.

If you find it, just replace the dependency on the MyEfDbContext for a dependency on a MyEfDbContext Factory object.

In that case, you can code yourself a factory class or you can use the Factory extension which would create the factory on the fly (https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory).

Hope that helps!